# Why MD5 Hash key is not matching with php generated MD5 Hash key?

Tags: java, android, hash, md5

In my Android application, I am using MD5 hash key for security of data access. I am using  Email+time+"postfix" string to generate the key. It is working good. But problem is, when I am using email address which has at least one plus (`+`) sign like `a+b@gmail.com`, the server is returning "incorrect access key" message. I noticed that it is working with email addresses with minus (`-`) , underscore (`_`), etc. sign, but it is not working with email addresses with plus (`+`) sign. I am generating MD5 Hash key with this method:

```
public static String MD5_Hash(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it :-

```
public static String getMD5(String input) {

 byte[] source;
 try {
     source = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     System.out.println("Error!");
 }

 String result = null;
 char hexDigits[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
         '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
 try {
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     md.update(source);
     byte temp[] = md.digest();
     char str[] = new char[16 * 2];
     int k = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         byte byte0 = temp[i];
         str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
         str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
     }
     result = new String(str);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("Error!");
}
return result;
}
```